# How can I get a one-off GPS location in Monodroid

Tags: android, gps, xamarin.android

I'm writing an application which requires that an accurate GPS location is taken at the moment a particular action is taken - specifically, by law we have to prove that we were at someone's house when we said we were.

I have already implemented a Location Listener to update the location for live-tracking purposes, but I also require an on-demand update from the device's GPS.

Using *GetLastKnownLocation* does not appear to force the GPS device to update - instead, I am getting the last location received from the *onLocationChanged* event.

Is there a way to force a device to update and get the **current** location, instead of either getting the last known location or waiting for another *onLocationChanged* event to fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Thread that runs at a particular interval of time and gets the location data..
So that you can use it later..

Comment: I used this method to get the location every 1 second and stores it in a variable. This thread starts when the visit process is started, and retries every 1 second until it gets a location with better accuracy than the stored location.